# HTTP POST request fails over 128k using Django/flup

Tags: django, post, fastcgi, mod-fcgid, flup

SO a form I have takes an image and uploads it. This produces an error when the image is over 128k, otherwise it works fine.

I don't have the error message, because it tries to render 500.shtml, which I don't have a template for in Django, so Django considers it a 404 (go figure). Notice the .shtml, this is not Django's regular 500 error, its the server. I am on shared hosting.

Using Django 1.4.5, Flup 1.0.3, Python 2.6.6

I've tried LimitRequestBody directive in my .htaccess, no effect

Additional details:
This occurs both in the django admin interface, and on a custom form/view I've made. The view does not get executed. I have tried different file storage approaches (plain/filesystem and django-storages(s3boto). Everything works great so long as the file is under 128 KB

**Update** - no resolution: Talked at length with my hosting company. Checked other settings, etc. Unable to reproduce when deploying in local test environment. Ended up using a workaround on live site (using existing URL instead of live upload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was contacted by hosting company:

> We just had another ticket in regarding this and were able to correct the issue. The fix is outline below.
>
> We adjusted the value to FcgidMaxRequestLen 1000000000 in the apache config as outlined > http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/config-mod_fcgid-related-maxrequestlen-timeout-214031.html#post1008351
>
> If anyone is still having this issue let us know via a ticket and we will be happy to adjust the value for the server your on as well.
>
> Thanks
>
> The topic can be found here: http://forums.asmallorange.com/topic/16354-django-and-media-uploads/?view=getnewpost

Just if anyone views this question in the future. Glad to know it wasn't my fault, at least. Too bad it took so long to resolve.